# Tag cleanup--[light]

Tags: discussion

> [Chat link](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/71?m=3826410#3826410), [Another one](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/71?m=4136095#4136095)

I'm currently retagging all questions tagged [light](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/light) to [visible-light](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visible-light) and/or [electromagnetic-radiation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electromagnetic-radiation)

Since editing them all at once will flood the main page, I'll keep track of them here, and slowly work my way through them.

Feel free to help! (try to do maximum 5 at a time)

Final destination is this synonym: https://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/visible-light/synonyms

No need to vote for it, a mod will synonymify it once the retagging is done.

> There now is a userscript for this https://gist.github.com/2994654 (full details [here](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/121541) ).

**EDIT:** the synonym has been created, so the link [light](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/light) doesn't work anymore. Use [this Data.SE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/75871/posts-tagged-light) instead.

Comment: I was coming to suggest that these kinds of changes should be discussed before implementation, but I see that you *have* been talking about it on chat with DavidZ. That's good. A link to the chat wouldn't hurt just so that it doesn't look like you are taking large scale unilateral action. Oh, and I like the change including make the [light]->[visible-light] synonym.

Comment: @dmckee: Added, good point about `large scale unilateral action`.

Answer (score 2):

Working my way from [the back](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/light?page=4&sort=newest&pagesize=50) (first page from the back categorised)

Note that not all pages need to be tagged [electromagnetic-radiation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electromagnetic-radiation) or [visible-light](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visible-light). Posts in the third section especially. Always read the post first--i've done the categorization based on the snippets.

Also, try to improve the post wherever possible. And put other relevant tags.

Update: I (and DavidZaslavsky) have finished retagging all posts on this page, will dig up more from the tag list and add another CW answer (to keep it neat)

### To be tagged [electromagnetic-radiation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electromagnetic-radiation)

Commented out for neatness' sake

### To be tagged [visible-light](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visible-light)

Commented out

### Not really [visible-light](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visible-light)

- [What does the optical zoom in telescopes do?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2187/what-does-the-optical-zoom-in-telescopes-do) DONE
- [Can light emitting diodes be used to generate UV wavelengths?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2542/can-light-emitting-diodes-be-used-to-generate-uv-wavelengths) DONE
- [Do mirrors increase the amount of light in a room?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2928/light-mirrors) DONE
- [Are regular light bulbs better for the eyes than CFLs or "tube lights"?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7395/are-regular-light-bulbs-better-for-the-eyes-than-cfls-or-tube-lights) DONE

### Both?

- [What causes hot things to glow, and at what temperature?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/550/what-causes-hot-things-to-glow-and-at-what-temperature) DONE

Comment: Keep in mind that some questions may not deserve the [tag:light] tag at all (i.e. the tag should just be removed, not changed to either [tag:visible-light] or [tag:electromagnetic-radiation]).

Comment: @David I know, a few of the 'not really VL' need that. After your clarification on the VL tag, I still need to recategorize some of those..

Comment: Yeah, that was more a note to anyone else who might be participating in this effort.

Answer (score 1):

This is for the next bunch of cleanup items(too much clutter on one post)

Note that this classification is rough, just so that I can get an overview.

Please read the full post before retagging, and improve if possible.

### Tag [electromagnetic-radiation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electromagnetic-radiation)

Commented out

### Tag [visible-light](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visible-light)

Commented out

### Both

[Do and can phone signals come inside AC car which is glass-packed](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/9799/do-and-can-phone-signals-come-inside-ac-car-which-is-glass-packed) DONE