# Tag cleanup chat session

Tags: discussion, chat, tags

Recently we've had some efforts to clean up the tags on the site ([example](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1166/tag-cleanup-light)), so I've created a chat event to collect any input that the community - that's you - may want to offer. It's scheduled for this Friday at <s>20:00</s> 15:00 UTC (though that could be changed if more people speak up soon), and you can see the details and "register" by going to the chat room's [schedule page](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/71/the-coupling?tab=schedule). Hope to see you there!

(This is not a question in any way, just an announcement, but seeing as how there's no other way to get the word out, I thought it would be important.)

Answer (score 1):

I myself live in IST, so 1:30 Saturday morning is a *tad* too early.

Though I don't think I have much input on this anyway--not found any strange tags recently. I'll look through the taglist and find vague stuff.

Another thing: We could use this to create tagwikiexcerpts. There are lots of vague tags that I've come across (I'll look for them), that lack excerpts. Since the excerpt tells you waht sort of questions belong there, you can't write the excerpts without, well, *knowing* the excerpt :/. So it would be nice if the tag scopes are discussed as well.

## Dumping ground

(I'll use this place to dump any tag-related stuff I find in the meantime--we can discuss these if necessary)

### Merges

[astronomy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astronomy)-->[astrophysics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astrophysics)

[atmosphere](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atmosphere)-->[atmospheric-sciences](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atmospheric-sciences)

[aircraft](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aircraft)<--[airplanes](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airplanes)

[rotational-dynamics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rotational-dynamics)/[rotational-kinematics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rotational-kinematics)

[lagrangian-mechanics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lagrangian-mechanics)/[lagrangian-formulism](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lagrangian-formulism)

[electric-circuits](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electric-circuits)-->[electrical-engineering](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electrical-engineering) ([synonym as well](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/electrical-engineering/synonyms))

### Burninate

[air](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/air) (dunno about this)

[beam](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beam)

[sign-convention](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sign-convention) -- Sort of a meta tag; sign conventions can be anywhere. Dunno about this.

[matrix-elements](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matrix-elements)

There are also lots of tiny tags like [escape-velocity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/escape-velocity). If you look backwards from [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tags?page=18&tab=popular), you get quite a few of them.  Only one question, and probably won't be needed again. We may want to discuss what do do with these. I say we destroy them all :)

### In need of tagwikiexcerpt

### Other

Split [radiation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radiation) into [electromagnetic-radiation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electromagnetic-radiation),[thermal-radiation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thermal-radiation), and [radioactivity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radioactivity) (with an option for [alpha-decay](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alpha-decay)/[beta-decay](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beta-decay))

Comment: Hm, well I pretty much picked that time randomly, I figured I'd change it based on community input. How would you feel about 1500 UTC?

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky: Still seems late to me--but I can participate from a tablet at that time. Which means I can discuss but carrying out [large scale unilateral action](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1166/tag-cleanup-light#comment2719_1166) becomes a bit tough. But I guess we'll be discussing, so it's OK. :)

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky: Anyway, I'll register myself and try to make it at 1500

Comment: Whoa, the [tags new tab](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=new) has tons of stuff that needs retagging.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky: What would be nice would be a minor edit button so that we can do this without bumping. Though this has been declined on MSO :/ .

Comment: Before deleting the newly created small tags (with only on question or so) one should probably check if they should be kept because they were used at the Astro or TP sites.