# Would astronomy or astrophysics questions be considered on topic here?

Tags: discussion, site-salvage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If it's possible, do we want to expand the scope of this site to include astronomy?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1197/if-its-possible-do-we-want-to-expand-the-scope-of-this-site-to-include-astrono)

Astronomy.SE is [closing](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170/astronomy-is-closing)l and this SE seems like it could be a natural home for a significant fraction of the questions asked there.  Before taking the time to flag anything for migration the question of what would/not be accepted here needs to be resolved.

Comment: A great deal of [astronomy and astrophysics](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/725/what-should-be-sent-to-astronomy-stackexchange) is [*already* on-topic](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/18/astronomy-astrophyiscs-related-question-here) here. And David Z. seems to have you beat by a few minutes.

Comment: Thanks for asking Dan :-) We will definitely be hashing this out over the next few days and I hope we will have your input.

Comment: @dmckee Figures.  I didn't see his question, I was probably typing mine when his posted.