# Are these questions appropriate here?

Tags: discussion, site-salvage

In the wake of the migration from Astronomy, there are a couple of questions that may or may not be appropriate on this site, which I would like to get the community's feedback on.

[Who should I contact if I see an unknown object in the sky?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/25185/who-should-i-contact-if-i-see-an-unknown-object-in-the-sky#question)

[Ways of verifying the origin of a meteorite?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/25188/ways-of-verifying-the-origin-of-a-meteorite#question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I agree with you that both are good for what it's worth. The closing of Astro means we need to pick up the slack, and that includes some pure astro questions. I didn't realize it was a migration due to site closing, so I said something else originally in comments, but I think that they are appropriate now.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, both of these questions seem on topic for astro. This question:[if-its-possible-do-we-want-to-expand-the-scope-of-this-site-to-include-astrono](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1197/if-its-possible-do-we-want-to-expand-the-scope-of-this-site-to-include-astrono) seems to indicate that essentially all of astro is now within scope (with the exception of astrophotography). Is this correct? I haven't looked at chat sessions or anything, and it's quite possible that I missed another meta question related to this. If so, a pointer would be helpful.

Is there a final policy or at least rough consensus on what the new scope is? Is it (Physics U Astro) or something else?

Comment: That question was the official discussion on changing the scope. The community seems to be in favor so we are going to do that - as of Friday our scope now includes astronomical questions. (And that reminds me, I need to update the FAQ)