# Did Astronomy.SE reopen?

Tags: discussion

As far as I know Astronomy.SE [merged](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1197/if-its-possible-do-we-want-to-expand-the-scope-of-this-site-to-include-astrono) into Physics.SE.

Recently I asked this astronomy related question: [When Venus is the brightest when viewed from Earth?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/89350/when-venus-is-the-brightest-when-viewed-from-earth)

Then I got a moderator comment that it would better fit in astronomy.SE.

So what's up? Will the site split again?

Answer (score 10):

Technically speaking, it is not reopened. Rather it is a [new](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40709/astronomy) SE proposal with the [same name](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/51/astronomy), although it might be difficult to tell [the difference in scope](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6222/40978). So in practice: *Yeah,* it reopened.

Answer (score 9):

The site was restarted. Old questions merged with Physics stay here.

Also, since our scope was expanded, everything on topic on Astro *is* on topic here, though for observational astronomy there is a chance that you may get better answers on Astro.

No, there are no plans of splitting up the scope again.

Comment: In other words, the new Astro.SE should be closed as a duplicate?

Comment: @bernhard Sort of, but that needs to happen in the definition phase of the site. Here, those who wanted the site wanted to be separate from Physics. SE allows subset sites if there is enough support.