# The fine line between astronomy and physics

Tags: discussion, scope, questions, migration

So, a few questions recently came up on the feed:

- [What is Venus's core made of?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/269376/2451)
- [How can core of Mercury be a molten liquid?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/269401/2451)

They made me wonder: when does something belong on the astronomy.SE and when does something belong on the physics.SE (this could also apply for chemistry, electrical engineering, etc)?

Comment: Related: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/1197/2451

Comment: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/725/  dates from the era of the first [astronomy.se], but I stand by the answer I wrote there.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see anything come up when I did a search for related questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since astronomy is [within our scope](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1197/if-its-possible-do-we-want-to-expand-the-scope-of-this-site-to-include-astrono), most things that would fit on Astronomy SE also fit here. If they are asked here, they should not be migrated. There are probably a few corner cases that are off topic for us and on topic for them, but those are rare.

For other topics, in principle it's straightforward: a question which is about physics (or astronomy) is on topic here, one which is not about physics (or astronomy) is off topic here. Of course, there can be some debate about whether something is about physics/astronomy or not, but again, those ambiguous cases are relatively rare.