# How are merges with other SEs executed?

Tags: discussion, site-salvage

There's currently a lot of [talk](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1197/if-its-possible-do-we-want-to-expand-the-scope-of-this-site-to-include-astrono) [about](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1193/full-migration-of-theoretical-physics-se-questions-to-physics-se) Physics.SE absorbing [ThPhys.SE](http://theoreticalphysics.stackexchange.com) and [Astro.SE](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com).  How is this carried out? Who decides, and where, on what policy is to be executed?  Once it's decided, where, how and when is it carried out? Is there a top-down decision or is there a "suggestions box" of some sort?

I couldn't seem to find any similar mass-migrations that have happened before, so apologies if this information is sitting in an obvious place I missed...

Comment: I think that we're making it up as we go along. Presumably the team will manage the ugly details of mass migration and then we clean up the mess.

Answer (score 4):

The SE team secretly decides in their underground hideout.

Seriously, though, they are taking input on *what* is to be done, though probably not on ipthe internal details. Just ask on http://meta.stackoverflow.com (or here if it is Phy.SE related), and they ought to come by. If you're quick enough, @GraceNote is currently online on Physics chat, so you can ask her. Otherwise, you can probably find @Shog9 on the MSO Tavern.

The changes will be discussed by the Phy.SE community, but the final decision rests in the hand of SE. But they (usually) listen to us, so practically "we decide".

Answer (score 3):

The gist of it is as follows: on Friday, SE will automatically migrate all non-closed questions from TP and Astro to Physics, and then will take those other sites offline.

The migrated questions will presumably have to be retagged by us, which is going to be an extended effort we'll have to get into after the migration.

Comment: Thanks for this. Will the migrated questions have a tag like "migrated"? Or some other mark that makes them visible, even if only to mods?

Comment: I'm not sure, you would have to ask one of the SE team about that.