# Renaming visible-light?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

I've noticed the [visible-light](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visible-light) tag has a tendency to be incorrectly applied in cases where the OP happened to have visible light in mind when they asked the question, but they are really asking about electromagnetic radiation in general. ([recent example](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/375010/whats-the-difference-between-low-energy-photons-and-high-energy-photons), and there are many other [visible-light](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visible-light) questions which I think should really have [electromagnetic-radiation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electromagnetic-radiation) instead) I've been thinking for a while that most of the questions which really deserve to be tagged [visible-light](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visible-light) are actually asking about color or visual perception, and I think if we were to rename the tag to something like [color-perception](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color-perception) or [visual-perception](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visual-perception) or so on, it would probably cut down on its misuse. What do you think - should we make this change and what is a good replacement name for the tag?

For background, [this question](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1166/tag-cleanup-light) collects some resources related to why we introduced the [visible-light](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visible-light) tag in the first place. It was an effort to break apart the old [light](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/light) tag into questions about EM radiation in general and questions not asking about EM radiation.

Comment: There's a *lot* of questions in that tag, and from a first brush with the top scorers I see a bunch of them where I don't really see the benefit of removing it. Can you provide some more examples of the questions where you think it's being misused? In any case, a straight rename of something with that much stuff in it is extremely likely to mischaracterize a large number of questions.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Good point, I'll have to take some time to collect examples, but I will edit the question accordingly when I have a chance.